# How to apply hasMany relation from Laravel Model in inertia ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, laravel, eloquent-relationship, inertiajs

I am trying to **display comments** that are related to individual posts from the db. Displaying the comments with that post inside my React component (**inertia**),
**using eloquent relations in Laravel**.

###### This is my PostController:

```php
public function show()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return Inertia::render('Posts', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }
```

###### My eloquent relation inside my Post model:

```php
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
```

###### This array of posts is send to my react component, inside my props (props.posts):

```php
{props.posts.map((post, key) => {
    console.log(post.comments);

    return (
        <div key={key}>
            {post.title}
            <ul>
                // map of post.comments (with hasMany relation)
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
        
})}
```

When logging inside my map of posts i receive a value of **undefined**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to load the comments relation before sending it to inertia

```php
    public function show()
    {
        $posts = Post::with('comments')->get();
        return Inertia::render('Posts', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you! It helped me on my way. As a newbie, I did need some additional doc on predefining and loading relational data. It works now :)